# radio type button js printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a web pages and i've almost done it. I have one last problem i do not even know what to try to solve it; 0 ideas.
I have a grid of 9 radio type button on top and another 9 grid radio button below it. the first one is for measures of a package while the other is for the weight. I have 2 variables to work with. PV_it and PV_eu. the data about these 2 variable are already written in a js function i tried to make (they're in couple, if PV_it is 0.83 PV_eu is 0.99 and so on). Here's the problem: I have to create a function that calculate which has the higher value between PV_it or peso (peso = weight) and then print this one higher inside a div where I already have placed some text. Can someone help me? I have no clue how to do it, logically neither, i don't know even what to try...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.niente').forEach(function(input) {
            input.onchange = function() {
                peso = this.value
            }
        })

        document.querySelectorAll('.ciccia').forEach(function(input) {
            input.onchange = function() {
                PV_it = this.name
                if (PV_it == 0.83) {
                    PV_eu == 0.99
                } else if (PV_it == 1.65) {
                    PV_eu == 1.98;
                } else if (PV_it == 2.48) {
                    PV_eu == 2.98;
                } else if (PV_it == 4.13) {
                    PV_eu == 4.96;
                } else if (PV_it == 5.83) {
                    PV_eu == 7.00;
                } else if (PV_it == 8.20) {
                    PV_eu == 9.84;
                } else if (PV_it == 12.49) {
                    PV_eu == 14.99;
                } else if (PV_it == 16.67) {
                    PV_eu == 20.00;
                } else if (PV_it == 25.00) {
                    PV_eu == 30.00;
                }
            }
        })
/*this is what i came up with to give the variables the right value based on which radio type button has been clicked*/
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.justify {
  justify-content: center;
}

.align {
  align-items: center;
}

.evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.m-0 {
  margin: 0;
}

.spacer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bg {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.tabtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tariffe {
  font-size: small;
}

.intro {
  text-align: center;
}

.tartitle {
  font-size: medium;
}

div h2 {
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.cont {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cont2 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.m-7 {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.m-14 {
  margin: 14px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

div input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.richiedi {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 50px;
}

.tabcosti {
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.border {
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.black {
  color: black;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

.m-left-50 {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.x-small {
  font-size: x-small;
}

.tabcosti2 {
  border-top: 0px;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.margin-left {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.info {
  width: 215px;
  height: 20px;
}

.info2 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.small {
  font-size: small;
}

.unbtn {
  border: 0px;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.unbtn:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}


.btn {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 184px;
  height: 40px;
}

.btn2{
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 184px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="radio" class="justify m-30 evenly flex-row bg">
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont ciccia" type="radio" value="4960" name="0.83"> 31x16x10
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont ciccia" type="radio" value="9900" name="1.65"> 33x20x15
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont ciccia" type="radio" value="14875" name="2.48"> 35x25x17
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont ciccia" type="radio" value="24800" name="4.13"> 40x31x20
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont ciccia" type="radio" value="35000" name="5.83"> 40x35x25
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont ciccia" type="radio" value="49200" name="8.20"> 41x40x30
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont ciccia" type="radio" value="74925" name="12.49"> 45x45x37
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont ciccia" type="radio" value="100000" name="16.67"> 50x50x40
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont ciccia" type="radio" value="150000" name="25.00"> 60x50x50
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<div id="radio2" class="flex-row bg m-7 justify evenly">
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont niente" type="radio" value="1" name="1"> 0-1 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont niente" type="radio" value="2" name="2"> 1-2 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont niente" type="radio" value="3" name="3"> 2-3 kg
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont niente" type="radio" value="4" name="4"> 3-5 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont niente" type="radio" value="7" name="7"> 5-7 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont niente" type="radio" value="10" name="10"> 7-10 kg
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont niente" type="radio" value="15" name="15"> 10-15 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont niente" type="radio" value="20" name="20"> 15-20 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont niente" type="radio" value="30" name="30"> 20-30 kg
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--this is where i have to print the higher number (inside <p> inside the <div> tabcosti2). -->
<div class="justify evenly flex-row">
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p>TARIFFA DI GESTIONE</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p>TARIFFA DI RESO</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p>TARIFFA DI STOCCAGGIO</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tabcosti evenly justify flex-row">
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p id="reso">€ <span class="white"></span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p>€ <span class="white"></span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p>€ <span class="white"></span> <span class="x-small">al mese</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-row tabcosti2">
                <div class="flex-col justify">
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <p class="margin-left">€ <span class="orange sium"></span><span> spedizione</span> ITALIA</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <p class="margin-left">€ <span class="orange sium"></span><span> spedizione</span> EUROPA</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <p class="margin-left">€ <span class="orange sium"></span><span> spedizione</span> WORLDWIDE*
                            ZONA 6</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col spacer"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi Filippo, I can see that there are some problem in your code... The radio buttons are meant to be used as a single choice between multiple values. They should all have the same "name" property if you want to use them that way. If you want to still allow multiple choices, then you should use a Checkbox instead.

Comment: Also, when you initialize PV_it you use the "value" attribute, which will be equal to, for example, "4960", not "0.83". I would suggest you to check out some tutorial or guide on how to use these elements, that would give you a good base to build upon :)

Comment: you are right, i forgot they have to be with the same name to be a single choice. But now i completely have 0 clue on how i should do it. how can i say that if u click one radio button, there's a variable that will take a value that is not in the html? i cannot use a different "value" cause I used them to do other function. I'm panicking

Comment: You could use an nested object. the key of the parent obkect being the value of our input and the keys of the child object PV_it and PV_eu. This would look like that:
`{'4960': {PV_it: 0.83, PV_eu: 0.99}, '9900': {PV_it: 1.65, PV_eu: 1.98}, …}`

Comment: Another option would be to use [data-* attributes]{https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*}
`<input type"radio" name="…" value="4960" data-pv-it="0.83" data-pv-eu="0.99" …>`

Comment: @FilippoCanino Yes you'd use that instead of the if/else if block

Comment: I red some days ago abou something like data-value, but for example if then i use "this.dat-value" it won't work, so how can i use the data-value?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by other commenters, the radios that belong together need to have the same name. In your script you'd then take the selected value and work with it.

Try this reactive vue example I have prepared.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      dimensions: [
        "31 x 16 x 10", "33 x 20 x 15", "35 x 25 x 17", "40 x 31 x 20", "40 x 35 x 25", "41 x 40 x 30", "45 x 45 x 37", "50 x 50 x 40", "60 x 50 x 50"
      ],
      weights: [
        "0 - 1", "1 - 2", "2 - 3", "3 - 5", "5 - 7", "7 - 10", "10 - 15", "15 - 20", "20 - 30"
      ],
      selectedDimension: -1,
      selectedWeight: -1,
      prices: [
        0.83, 1.65, 2.48, 4.13, 5.83, 8.2, 12.49, 16.67, 25
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    highestSelection() {
      return this.selectedDimension > this.selectedWeight? this.selectedDimension : this.selectedWeight;
    },
    managementFee() {
      return 0; // insert your calculation here
    },
    returnRate() {
      return 0; // insert your calculation here
    },
    storageFee() {
      return 0; // insert your calculation here
    },
    shipmentItaly() {
      return this.highestSelection != -1 ? this.prices[this.highestSelection]: 0; // just an example. insert your calculation here
    },
    shipmentEurope() {
      return this.shipmentItaly * 1.2; // just an example. insert your calculation here
    },
    shipmentWorldwide() {
      return this.shipmentItaly * 2; // just an example. insert your calculation here
    }
  },
  filters: {
    price(val) {
      return val.toFixed(2);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap');

#app {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

#app > * {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #eee;
}

.dimensions, .weights {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.prices {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="dimensions"><label v-for="(dimension, i) in dimensions" :key="`dimension-${i}`"><input type="radio" name="dimension" v-model="selectedDimension" :value="i">{{ dimension }} cm</label></div>
  <div class="weights"><label v-for="(weight, i) in weights"  :key="`weight-${i}`"><input type="radio" name="weight" v-model="selectedWeight" :value="i">{{ weight }} kg</label></div>
  <div class="prices">
    <div>TARIFFA DI GESTIONE</div>
    <div>TARIFFA DI RESO</div>
    <div>TARIFFA DI STOCCAGGIO</div>
    <div>{{ managementFee | price }} €</div>
    <div>{{ returnRate | price }} €</div>
    <div>{{ storageFee | price }} €</div>
  </div>
  <div class="shipments">
    <div>{{ shipmentItaly | price }} € spedizione ITALIA</div>
    <div>{{ shipmentEurope | price }} € spedizione EUROPA</div>
    <div>{{ shipmentWorldwide | price }} € WORLDWIDE* ZONA 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm sorry to tell you this, but isn't there another way to do it "simplier"? i've seen vue for a mini-lesson of 2 hour in school years ago and i know nothing, i'd like to use only thing that i now a little like js in a way that even if someone write me the code i should use i'm able to understand what i'm looking at, because for example in ur code i don't understand anything

Comment: I have simplified the HTML considerably and the JS code even has comments to show where you'd want to implement the logic you are searching for. In terms of vue, the code isn't using much more then v-for to loop through all dimensions and weights and one filter to transform a number to a fixed 2 digit value.